# force a different page template based on node id?

Tags: theming

Is it possible provide a page with an alternate template suggestion for a certain page?

e.g. i have a landing page. I have the node id. I would like to switch the page template if the node id is a certain number.

If it is how would you go about that in the theme preprocess function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ought to do it:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__node__' . $node->nid;
  }
}
```

And then call your template file `page--node--123.tpl.php`

Answer (score 1):

It is enough you name the page template file as page--node--[node ID].tpl.php, if you are using Drupal 7. (Replace [node ID] with the node ID.)

As shown in the example reported for [theme_get_suggestions()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7), that is 
one of the suggested templates.

> Build a list of suggested theme hooks or body classes in order of specificity. One suggestion is made for every element of the current path, though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent suggestions. For example, for `$base='page'`, http://www.example.com/node/1/edit would result in the following suggestions and body classes:
>
> - `page__node` `page-node`
> - `page__node__%` `page-node-%`
> - `page__node__1` `page-node-1`
> - `page__node__edit` `page-node-edit`

Similar comment is present in [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) for Drupal 6. The difference is that Drupal 6 uses one underscore when Drupal 7 uses two underscores. As consequence, in Drupal 6 the template filename must have a hyphen instead of two.

Keep in mind that the underscore for the suggested template name is replaced from a hyphen, when building the template filename.